Power BI Calculate Column Respecting Filters of a Slicer
first of all, the main problem is that I want to calculate the amount of rows related in the table crffe_clientcheckinlog with crffe_projects, here you have the model:

I've created a measure that does this well, the measure name is FlagClientCheckIn and it respects the date filters with a slicer attached to that table, in this case, the first project in the table has only 1 related row in crffe_clientcheckinlog for January but the calculated column FlagCheckCheck is not respecting the filters, I'm doing this to make the pie charts selectable and filter the main table below, if you can help me to calculate the column or giving me another approach to do the same, I'll thank you so much

My current formulas are these ones:
Measure (Well calculated):
FlagClientCheckIn = 
VAR CheckCount = CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(crffe_clientcheckinlog),
    crffe_clientcheckinlog[crffe_project] = SELECTEDVALUE(crffe_projects[Projects])
)
RETURN IF(CheckCount > 0, 1, 0)

Column (Calculating without filters):
FlagClientCheckIn = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(crffe_clientcheckinlog),
    crffe_clientcheckinlog[crffe_project] = SELECTEDVALUE(crffe_projects[Projects])
)


Calculated Columns are calculated and set when the dataset refreshes, runtime interactions like slicers/filters will not affect calculated columns. Update your question with this in mind, and provide more details on the chart/visual interaction you are aiming for, so we can assist further.
